# Store response.data in a global variable

Tags: javascript, post, axios

I'm trying to store response.data into a variable that can then be used outside of it's scope however it seems to always come back as undefined.

As you can see in the code, the first axios calls returns a token and then I later want to be able to use this token within the headers of the POST call.

```
const server = () => {
  var token;

  axios.get('http://xxxxx').then(
    response => {
      token = response.data;
    }
  );

  var configuration = {
    configToken: token
  };

  async function login() {
    return fetch('https://xxxx', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${configuration.configToken}`,
      },
    })
  }

  login();
};

export default server;
```

Comment: axios call is async and you called login   just after the axios get method , you should move it to promise callback and pass token to login method or use await before async call and get response without callback the call login method with token

Answer (score 0):

axios request you send depending on the server path. check if your server is https or http